# Selection of Forms just after program execution

Tags: delphi, c++builder

My Environment: C++ Builder XE4 on Windows7 pro(32bit)

I would like to select two forms automatically just after the user execute the software.

I have two forms as follows.

- FormStart : normally this shows up after program execution
- FormOther : this shows up when user specify run-time-parameter (e.g. /useOther)

When FormOther is shown, FormStart is not necessary to be shown.

I added following code in FormShow() of the TFormStart

```
TFormStart::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (useOther) {
        FormOther->ShowModal();
        this->Close();
    }
}
```

This seems work. 
When user close the FormOther, FormStart shows up and immediately closes. This behavior is what I expected, so O.K.

**What other way can we realize the above function?**

I tried the following, and had error ("You cannot change Visible in OnShow or OnHide");

So, I gave up using the following.

```
TFormStart::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (userOther) {
        FormOther->Show();
        this->Hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first form created by `Application.CreateForm` is the main form of the application, and when it's closed the application terminates.

To use a different form, you have to do so in the project (.dpr or .bpr) source instead. Use `Project->View Source` from the IDE main menu to get to it.

In [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi), it would look like this:

```pascal
program Project1;

uses
  Forms, SysUtils,
  StartForm in 'StartForm.pas' {FormStart},
  OtherForm in 'OtherForm.pas' {FormOther};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  if FindCmdLineSwitch('useOther') then
    Application.CreateForm(TFormOther, FormOther)
  else
    Application.CreateForm(TFormStart, FormStart);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

In [c++builder](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2bbuilder), it would look like this:

```cpp
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include <SysUtils.hpp>
#include <tchar.h>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

USEFORM("StartForm.cpp", StartForm);
USEFORM("OtherForm.cpp", OtherForm);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    try
    {
        Application->Initialize();
        Application->MainFormOnTaskBar = true;
        if (FindCmdLineSwitch("useOther"))
            Application->CreateForm(__classid(TFormOther), &FormOther);
        else
            Application->CreateForm(__classid(TFormStart), &FormStart);
        Application->Run();
    }
    catch (Exception &exception)
    {
        Application->ShowException(&exception);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        try
        {
            throw Exception("");
        }
        catch (Exception &exception)
        {
            Application->ShowException(&exception);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that modifying the project source can make maintenance difficult, as the IDE uses this for form information and dependencies. Sometimes changing it manually can cause issues.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It's interesting to know your way of selecting the forms. As you wrote, I have to take care when I modify the .dpr file for further maintenance.

Comment: Code in delphi is no problem for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: I added a C++ example, just in case someone else comes across this answer and does not understand Delphi.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness, Remy Lebeau. It will help when we have both code for further reference by others.

Comment: Rather than adding all that code to the project file which is prone to be modified (and messed up) by the IDE, I would put the logic into a function (e.g. main()) in a separate unit and call it from the project.

Comment: @Remy: Thanks very much for the edit. I didn't have a chance to provide the Builder equivalent (was going to do it sometime today). You even improved on my Delphi code in the process. I appreciate your efforts. :-)

Comment: @dummzeuch: I am not quite sure about your method. Is it possible to select forms with one binary execution file with your method, not in the building time?

Comment: @sevenOfNine: No, that's not what the suggestion says. It's saying you should write a function that would contain that code in a unit (source file) instead, and then call that function from the project file. (It would separate the code from the project file, meaning less potential conflict with the IDE.) I thought you'd be able to take what I (with Remy's assistance) wrote and figure out how best to use it in your actual app.

Comment: @Ken White: Thank you for your comments. I quite agree about the separation of the code to a unit source file for the clarity of the code and better maintenance.